# Multiple Replace functions on same column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need help with combining multiple replace/cast functions into the same query.

I already have a preexisting select statement for a particular column(col_name):

```
CAST(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(col_name, 1, 4000), '''', '''''') AS VARCHAR(4000)) AS col_name
```

I want to include a command to replace tabs within the column (loading from SQL Server to IBM db2 using Visual Studio and I have tabs within the columns of a tab-delimited table...super fun):

```
REPLACE(col_name, CHAR(9), '')
```

How would I combine these?

Comment: You could chain your "replace" but it's not pretty, or create a temporary table with a set of replace command. https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/multiple-replace-on-1-column-in-select-statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take your first statement:

```
CAST(replace(substring(col_name,1,4000),'''','''''') AS VARCHAR(4000)) as col_name
```

Replace the col_name in your second statement with the above cast statement:

```
REPLACE(CAST(replace(substring(col_name,1,4000),'''','''''') AS VARCHAR(4000)), CHAR(9), '') as col_name
```

Comment: It works, but not very readable. You should probably consider this alternative more elegant solution https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/multiple-replace-on-1-column-in-select-statement

Comment: It is exactly what the question asked. Also, even the post you are linking to states this: "It can be awkward to get all those pesky commas and brackets in the right place? Small price to pay for top performance. Nested REPLACE's are super-speedy."

Comment: yes, but I would avoid to chain 10 of them in the same query. it's not readable nor easily maintainable.

Comment: So you are ok with using code that takes longer and uses more processing because it's easier to read, got it.

Comment: Yes. Maintainability is essential in process design. You have to weight cost/benefit each time. Obviously, if the performance is dramatically impacted then choose the more performant solution.